# Ajax With JQuery MVC Form Posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm a complete Ajax noob and I'm finding myself a little lost in how to best approach things, I've been looking over SO and found a post about Ajax that included this JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I incorporated this into my scripts file for a form on one of the pages in my site and quickly realised this actually attaches to ALL the forms, site wide including the login form.

I want to treat the login form as a special case and actually perform a redirect rather than simply insert the returned HTML fragment into an element on the page.

I'm presuming that replacing 'form' with the ID of the login form will differentiate the login form from 'general' form handling processes and was wondering what are the accepted best practices for this.

Do you have a 'general' Ajax hander like the one above or is it better to have specific JavaScript functions for each form depending on what they need to do with the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you included something generic for a situation which should have been localized. In my opinion blanket approaches like this are not really desirable, especially not with something which is going to affect every form in your application.

The real meat of this to take away is the `$.ajax` code. Use ajax when you want, and use formal posting otherwise (which is default).

Using an exact reference will of course differentiate certain forms in your application, but this is something which should be done in a view's script, and not in one blanket script which is included application wide.

What I tend to do is use ajax when I want to provide a preview, or if I want to post *without* the user navigating away from the page.

Sometimes in rare occasions I will have a page which is replaced with a few sliding windows via ajax and then at the end of the series I will want to redirect. When that is the case, I will have my controller return a string which allows the view to redirect to that string in the success function of the ajax call.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not looking to do this in a general fashion, the code would end up in spaghetti hell in no time.  The separation of navigation you describe is exactly what I want to do in my site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep mine separate, though others may do differently. They post to different URLs and do different things with the data.

I refer to the form by id:

```
$('#myformid")
```

Comment: This is what I was suspecting, a login process is so vastly different to posting a bit of data back to a controller method, if it was handled conditionally the JavaScript handling the responses would become a monster in no time.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use the not equal selector if you just want to apply your function to all forms except your login form.

```
$('form[id!="loginform"]')...
```

Comment: Useful but I suspect you'd end up in the same situation in time, too many things being handled in one function.

Comment: In that case I would suggest giving all your ajax forms a class and selecting them that way. `$('.ajaxform')...`

Comment: Indeed, that would nicely cut down on potential JavaScript duplication for the majority of cases.